# what the conditions of $ \varlimsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} m\left(E_{n}\right)=1$ indicates

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

measurable set columns  $\left\{E_{n}\right\}$  in  $[0,1]$ , and
$
\varlimsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} m\left(E_{n}\right)=1
$

Prove that for $0<a<1$,  $\left\{E_{n_{k}}\right\}$ exists, s.t.
$$
m\left(\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} E_{n_{k}}\right)>a
.$$

I am not sure how to use the condition $
\varlimsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} m\left(E_{n}\right)=1
$ to get the results.

Anybody could help?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose $(n_{k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $\lim_{k \to \infty} m(E_{n_{k}}) = 1$.  Passing to a further subsequence, we can assume that $1 - m(E_{n_{k}}) < 2^{-k}$ for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$.  Hence
\begin{equation*}
m \left( \bigcup_{k = K}^{\infty} [0,1] \setminus E_{n_{k}}\right) < \sum_{k = K}^{\infty} 2^{-k} = 2^{-K}.
\end{equation*}
This implies
\begin{equation*}
m \left( \bigcap_{k = K}^{\infty} E_{n_{k}} \right) \geq 1 - 2^{-K}.
\end{equation*}

**Edit:** Fix $a \in (0,1)$.  There is a $K \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $1 - 2^{-K} > a$.  Define $(i_{\ell})_{\ell \in \mathbb{N}}$ by
\begin{equation*}
i_{\ell} = n_{K + \ell - 1}.
\end{equation*}
The above arguments imply that
\begin{equation*}
m \left( \bigcap_{\ell = 1}^{\infty} E_{i_{\ell}} \right) \geq 1 - 2^{-K} > a.
\end{equation*}

Comment: aww! thank you very much. I understand.

But sorry, how does it associate with 0<a<1, and how can we use the range of a to connect to the result with K. Thanks so much!

Comment: See the edit above.